# How to make qUnit assert after sinon.stub().resolves() in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5, sinon, qunit

I want to write test for `metadataLoaded` promise, sinon version is 4.1.2.

Promise resolve is called, but I don't know how to write proper test assert. Two asserts I've tied has failed.

```js
_onObjectMatched : function (oEvent) {
    var sObjectId =  oEvent.getParameter("arguments").objectId;
    this.getModel().metadataLoaded().then( function() {
        var sObjectPath = this.getModel().createKey("TaskSet", {
            id :  sObjectId
        });
    }.bind(this));
},

QUnit.test("_onObjectMatched", function(assert) {
    var oEventStub = {
        getParameter: sinon.stub().returns({objectId: "1"})
    };
    this.oModelStub = {
        createKey: sinon.stub().returns("key"),
        metadataLoaded :  jQuery.noop
    };
    sinon.stub(this.oModelStub, "metadataLoaded").resolves();

    this.oController._onObjectMatched(oEventStub);

    //Error: assert before promise resolves
    assert.ok(this.oModelStub.createKey.calledOnce, "createKey called");

    //Error: this.oModelStub.metadataLoaded.then is not a function
    this.oModelStub.metadataLoaded.then(function() {
        assert.ok(this.oModelStub.createKey.calledOnce, "createKey called");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is "this" in method and in the test case pointing to the same object? It looks like it's not. Anyway, this code should work:

```js
QUnit.test("_onObjectMatched", function(assert) {
    // ...
    // where obj - reference to the object with "_onObjectMatched" method
    sinon.stub(obj, "_onObjectMatched").returns({
        createKey: sinon.stub().returns("key"),
        metadataLoaded: function () {
            return Promise.resolve();
        }
    });
    // ...
});
```

Comment: `this.oController` in test case equals `this` in controller method.

Comment: I've changed the code, but still returns `this.oModelStub.metadataLoaded.then is not a function`

Comment: ```this.oModelStub.metadataLoaded()``` <--- you forgot braces, promise is wrapped into a function

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Skay, this is working:

```
this.oModelStub.metadataLoaded().then(function() {
    assert.ok(this.oModelStub.createKey.calledOnce, "createKey called");
}.bind(this));
```